# how to merge two dataframes with a function in the join condition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to merge two dataframes with a condition.

In the condition, there is a function calculating a float. Inputs for this function are strings converted to floats.

Here is my code:

```
def calculateStraightLineDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = pi/180
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p))/2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))


join_condition = [calculateStraightLineDistance(float(sd.lat_soc), float(sd.lon_soc),
                                               float(ad.lat_agen), float(ad.lon_agen)) <= 50.0 ]


merged_data = sd.join(ad, join_condition, 'left')
```

However, this code throws the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-7e6c5d9332f8> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 join_condition = [calculateStraightLineDistance(float(sd.lat_soc), float(sd.lon_soc),
     12                                                float(ad.lat_agen), float(ad.lon_agen)) <= 50.0 ]
     13 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. A previous condition, without any cast and function, worked fine. For example:

```
join_condition = [ad.lat_agen >=  sd.lat_soc]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Edit:

```
ad= spark.sql(agencies_query)
ad.lat_agen.cast("float")
ad.printSchema()
```

Will print:

```
|-- lat_agen: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lon_agen: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Steven's answer is what i could find on the net, I did not manage to make it work.

However, here how I achieved this:

```
ad = ad.withColumn("lat_gen", ad.lat_agen.cast(FloatType()))
```

A printSchema gives the expected output:

```
ad.printschema()
```

`|-- lat_agen: float (nullable = true`)

Answer (score 0):

you are applying a function `float` to a column `sd.lat_soc`.
`float`, as the message clearly says, accepts only string or number, not column object.
If you want the content of the column to be converted to float, use : `sd.lat_soc.cast("float")`.

Comment: When using `sd.lat_soc.cast("float")` , a describe of the dataframe still shows the column as a string. Why is that so ?

Comment: because you change it only in the join condition probably. therefore, it is just a temporary chang.

Comment: `ad= spark.sql(agencies_query)` followed by `ad.lat_agen.cast("float")` then a printSchema still shows the column `lat_agen` as a String (updated my question with these information)

Comment: Found a way while casting the column type during a withColumn statement.